# What is the correct way to persist input through a confirmation page and into a submission page in Laravel?

Tags: php, forms, session, laravel

I've been working on migrating several of our forms to Laravel, but there's one last step I'm not entirely sure on how to go about. I have a form that does an Insert into a database, but instead of just having 2 pages--the form and the submission page--I have 3: the form, a confirmation and a submission page.

Here is what I have at the moment:

Routes:

```
Route::any('application/housing-form', array('as'=>'application.form', 'uses'=>'ApplicationController@form'));
Route::post('application/confirmation', array('as'=>'application.confirmation', 'uses'=>'ApplicationController@confirmation'));
Route::post('application/submit', array('as'=>'application.submit', 'uses'=>'ApplicationController@submit'));
```

ApplicationController:

```
public function form()
{
    $application = new Application;
    return View::make('application/form')->with(array('application'=>$application));
}
public function confirmation()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    //More here?
    return View::make('application/confirmation')->with(array('input'=>$input));
}
public function submit() {
    $input = Input::all();
    DB::table('application')->insert(
        array(
            <field1>     => $input('field1')
            ...
             )
    );
    return View::make('application/submit');
}
```

Views:

```
//form
{{ Form::model($application, array('route'=>'application.confirmation')
    //inputs
    {{ Form::submit('Continue') }}
{{ Form::close() }}

//confirmation
{{ Form::open(array('route'=>'application.form') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Back to my information') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
{{ Form::open(array('route'=>'application.submit') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
{{ Form::close() }}

//submission
<p>Thank you for your submission!</p>
```

What I am unsure about is how to persist the data from the form through the confirmation page and into the submission page. From what I can tell, I can see a few options:

1. Reflash all of the input
2. Use a hidden field (or fields) to send the information
3. Insert the information into the database in the confirmation page and just do an update with an in-between query with the information.

I'm pretty sure it would be the first one: reflashing the data. But if so, I'm not sure where you're actually supposed to call Session::flash or Session::reflash. Or how many times I need to do it to get it through all of the requests. Any suggestions on how to go about that, or how to streamline the rest of the form would be greatly appreciated.

One extra note as well is that this particular form deals with a large number of input fields (around 60). That's part of why I want to avoid having to request each individual field to a minimum.

Comment: I'd just save it normally to the session and then delete it when you no longer need the input data.

Comment: I can't understand why when I go back to the original form, the Session is being automatically cleared. I'm saving it as per the documentation, but whenever I go back to the form, the session only contains the `token`. Is there something else where it would be automatically clearing the session? Or possibly that the fact that I'm binding the form to a new model each time I make the form?

Comment: How are you saving to the session? Like this: `Session:put('form-data', Request::all())`? (this is how you do it in Laravel 5)

Comment: It turns out that my problem with the Sessions was a file permissions issue. Each session in my app/storage/sessions was read-only, so there was one system user that wasn't able to access the sessions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is to flash the input to the session in order to repopulate the form. This can be achieved by using the Input::flash() method like so:

```
public function confirmation(){
    Input::flash(); //this will store the input to the session
    return View::make('application/confirmation');
}
```

Then in your view, use the Input::old() method to retrieve input data from the previous request:

```
{{ Form::text('fieldname', Input::old('fieldname')) }}
```

Comment: Would you be able to to explain your first section of code? It looks like there might be a redirect loop (that route will call the same controller it's contained in) Sorry if it was because my code was a little jumbled originally...

Comment: I didn't realise your route was a post method, so I've changed that line to View::make() instead.